# FluentValidation with mapping between 2 objects

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have a List that I need to maintain with all props being a string.
But now I would like to generate a new List that maps the properties and if validation fails it will set IsValid property of PersonSource to false and ValidationMessage to reasons why
I can also use AutoMapper if it is possible to add that into the mix
My validation class has bunch of data validation that ensure there is data and data is appropriate

```cs
 public class PersonSource
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string SomeNumber { get; set; }

        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public string ValidationMessage { get; set; }
    }


    public class PersonDest
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int SomeNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }


    }
    public class PersonDestValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonDest>
    {
        public PersonDestValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MaximumLength(50);

            RuleFor(x => x.LastName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MaximumLength(50);

            RuleFor(x => x.BirthDate)
                .LessThan(DateTime.UtcNow);


            RuleFor(x => x.SomeNumber)
                .GreaterThan(0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear, i don't understand what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

FluentValidation is going to return a `ValidationResult` after you've validated your `PersonDest` object.

To map this object to a new `PersonSource` object, enriched with the validation results, my first thought would be to use AutoMapper and provide a [custom type converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html). Custom type converters can take a `ResolutionContext` which is the container you'd use to get your validation results into the mapping process.

The converter `Convert` method would look something like this:

```
public PersonSource Convert(PersonDest personDest, PersonSource personSource, ResolutionContext context){
    if (personSource == null)
    {
        personSource = new PersonSource();
    }

    if (personDest == null)
    {
        return personSource;
    }

    ... PersonDest to PersonSource mapping

    var validationResult = (ValidationResult)context.Items["ValidationResult"]

    personSource.IsValid = validationResult.IsValid

    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        personSource.ErrorMessage = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validationResult.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage))
    }
}
```

The `ResolutionContext.Mapper` property provides access to the mapper, so it may be possible to define the basic PersonDest to PersonSource mapping in your mapping profile and use that in your type converter. You may run into a recursive loop with the `ConvertUsing` extension. Experiment and let us know how you go.